# Python-SocketIO server takes a long time to fire event

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, socket.io, aiohttp

I have a python websocket server attempting to communicate with a javascript websocket client (embedded in HTML). The events are being `emit`ed from the server immediately, but it takes upwards of 30 seconds for the server to send the event trigger, despite both the client and server being locally hosted.

Here is the relavent code for the server:

```py
sio = socketio.AsyncServer(cors_allowed_origins='*')
app = web.Application() #aiohttp web server
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
sio.attach(app)

async def index(request):
    with open('./index.html') as f:
        return web.Response(text=f.read(), content_type='text/html')

app.router.add_get('/', index)
app.router.add_get('/index.html', index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(app)
```

the event is being fired like so (edit, this must be done with event loops, as `emit` is an asynchronous function being run from a synchronous one.):

```py
print('Starting event')
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(sio.emit('ChangeProgressState'))
loop.close()
print('Event has been fired.')
```

However, the print statements show up immediately. On the client end, I am connecting and trying to consume the event like this:

```js
const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080", {
      transports: ['websocket']
})

socket.on("ChangeProgressState", function (data) {
    console.log("got event.")
    //some code here...
});
```

However, from the time it takes for the event to fire, and the time it takes for the javascript socket to notice can be a very long time, from 30 seconds to sometimes a few minutes. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

It should be noted, there are very little (2%-5%) resources being consumed (both memory and CPU), so I do not currently think that is the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT 11/15/2019: I have tried looking at the networking tab of the application (chromium-browser on raspberry pi). It seems to show the initial socket connection, but it doesn't show anything in terms of communication between sockets, even after the event eventually fires.

EDIT 2: This definitely seems to be an issue server-side. I can send events from the JS client to the python server essentially immediately, but going in the other direction is when it takes a long time to arrive. I'm not quite sure why though.

Comment: For clarity, is it 30 seconds to a few minutes that it takes to see "got event." being printed in the console on the client? If your client is a browser (instead of say node.js) does the network tab (dev tools) for your browser for the socket connection show anything helpful?

Comment: Do events really get emitted in a loop like this, can you not just call sio.emit('ChangeProgressState')? Not a python guy, but seems odd

Comment: @Chev no worries, if you aren't familiar with python this is a little more complex to understand. Essentailly, the sio.emit is an asynchronous function, but in order to call it from a synchronous function you have to first create an event loop, and call the method from there.

Comment: @ArthurWeborg Yes, it's 30 seconds or whatever time until I get the log message that the message was received.

Comment: @Tmello225 how time passes between your two print statements above?

Comment: @Chev It's essentially immediate, sub 1 second

Comment: @Tmello225 can you try use HTTP and not WebSockets. You have mentioned chrome on rasperry pi, python API and also using the JS socket.io client. I'd start a process of elimination and test with a simple node.js socket.io server and also test from desktop version of chrome and find the culprit through the process of elimination.

Comment: @Chev after some investigating, it seems clear this is a serverside (python) issue. I can send messages at a normal pace going from client to server, but not the other way around. The actual `emit` method finishes immediately, but nothing is being sent until later.

Comment: Great find. I don't know Python but the statement `run_until_complete` _sounds_ like is running more than once and maybe some odd throttling/queuing going on in the background. Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to everyone that helped answering this question! I finally found a solution that is a bit unorthodox, so I'll explain the whole situation here.

Essentially, in order to run an async method in a synchronous context, you must use the asyncio's `run_until_complete` method on an event loop. This is how I was doing it when this question was asked. However, after talking to the creator of the python-socketio library, it seems that you must run this in the same event loop as the one the server is running in.

However, this creates a different problem. If an event loop is already running, python does not allow you to use run_until_complete on it, giving you an error: `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running.`

So, this things sound contradictory right? And you would be correct. However, this problem is prevalent enough that another library exists for the sole purpose of monkey-patching the python asyncio library to fix this problem. I found this library [here](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7096#issuecomment-449655308) .

After installing and utilizing that library, I can now do this, which fixes my problem completely:

```py
main_event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
main_event_loop.run_until_complete(sio.emit("ChangeProgressState"))
```

Now the program runs as expected, and the messages are being sent/arriving immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok, so my gut said it sounds like the client is long polling. Many socket libraries first establish long-polling and then upgrade to ws connections.

After taking a look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/docs/):

> ... which first establishes a long-polling connection, then tries to upgrade to better transports that are “tested” on the side, like WebSocket. ...

So I don't believe you're doing anything wrong, it's just the initialization process of establishing the WebSocket connection.

As for the python part, I'll be honest that's a tad more fuzzy to me. My first guess is that the loop code doesn't block the print statement from being executed -- but I'm more familiar with JavaScript than Python, so not completely certain on that front. My second guess is that I do know from other pub/sub libraries that the server side engine sometimes makes use of a middle layer of sorts (sometimes a cache, sometimes a queue) that helps ensure messages are sent/received, that's also a possibility.

extra tidbit: I suspect if you look at the network tab of your browser's dev tools, it'd display that behavior, some form of HTTP requests, and then eventually you'd see the socket connection. Playing around with turning your Python server/service off/on would also demonstrate the robustness of socket.io in the browser and edge cases for how it handles unstable networking when communicating with respect to various internet communication protocols.

Comment: Thanks for the response Arthur. After some investigating, it seems clear this is a serverside (python) issue. I can send messages at a normal pace going from client to server, but not the other way around. The actual emit method finishes immediately, but nothing is being sent until later.

Comment: Nice detective work, @tmello225, I second Chev's thoughts on checking out the communication in known stable environments and possible swapping out the server. 

Note, looking at the [python documentation](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#emitting-events) a little bit more, I don't see anything about emiting needing to wait for connections to emit a message -- is it possible that your loop does in fact emit, it's just nothing receives that message? Would there be any target line of code that you'd expect would wait for the connection before emitting that event?

Comment: I'll delete my answer if you determine it's not helpful, sounds like you are really close! definitely be sure to write up an answer when you get to the bottom of everything :) I may find some time to poke around looking at pyhton-socketio, but in the event I don't, best regards digging!